# How to copy table data from PDF to excel

Tags: pdf, copy-paste

When I copy data in a table like this from a PDF, it gets translated into plain text without any delimiting characters to distinguish which column the data is in.

[image: PDF table with highlighted rows]

It would be helpful if I could highlight only a single column in the pdf at a time, but it currently tries to select left to right both columns as I highlight. Is there any trick for this?

Comment: For something like this, I would paste it into Excel and then use Excel's parsing functions to pull apart the data into separate cells.

Comment: @JimFell If this is a "one time only" instance I would recommend the same.

Comment: @Geditdk Unfortunately, I think this is just a limitation of working with PDF files.  Short of investing in a professional PDF editor, maybe you could write an Excel macro or custom VB function to speed up the process.

Comment: Scripting is a good idea but You could use the Microsoft word "convert to table" function?

Comment: Similar questions: https://superuser.com/questions/1289783/how-can-i-copy-a-table-of-data-from-a-pdf-file-into-excel, https://superuser.com/questions/161535/copy-a-table-from-pdf-as-a-table

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Holding down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key should allow you to select a column of text.

(Note: I've only tested this with Acrobat Pro, not Acrobat Reader.)

Comment: Works in Adobe Reader as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As of 2021/Office 365, you should be able to simply open the pdf in Word, then copy the resulting Word table into Excel.

Comment: This worked perfectly even when the "use alt to select a column" did not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Microsoft word "Convert to table" function outlined [here](http://www.economicsnetwork.ac.uk/tips/pdf2excel).

It's not exactly what you need but at least it is quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Try to upload it to Google Docs and then save as XLS file, it should work

Answer (score 1):

If automatic conversion with the tools suggested above fail, there's always selecting one individual column at a time while pressing ALT, then pasting in Excel each column individually. It's crude, but quite reliable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not straight forward, however there are a large number of free or cheap services in the cloud for extracting such tables from PDFs.

Please find below the comparison table automated table extraction solutions according to [Zanran](http://pdf.zanran.com/review01.html):

[image: Review of online PDF to Excel services, March 2016 by Zanran]

So based on above, you may consider [Zanran's Table Xtractor](http://pdf.zanran.com/) which has ability to finds the tables in your PDFs and converts them to Excel.

Comment: Note: A free demo seems to be available for a single file but it requires you to fill in personal information and email to receive a link to the result.